# How to display external web page in mvc 5?

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-5, html, partial-views

I would like to display another web sides inside my mvc view.

Can anyone help me how to do this issue? I tried using iframe but i could not succeed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<iframe>` or `<embed>` or `<object>` tags in HTML5 to display 3rd other websites URL inside your application.
Example:

```
 <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://modernpathshala.com" width="600" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is normal should be displaying website in frame. when i try in chrome it is not displaying anything but when i try to display in IE it is showing that "This content cannot be displayed in a frame." That was the reason why i can not display website in my web page.

Comment: Hi @Ert, Yes there is setting X-Frame-Options on the server, if this is enabled then we can not open that site in the iFrame. The value of x-Frame-Options header can be checked in the response headers by browsing any website.

Answer (score 1):

```
<object type="text/html" data="External_URL" width="500px" height="500px">
    </object>
```

Note : replace External_URL with your url

Comment: When i use in my view like below it is not working.
<blink>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Intranet";
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }

    <div>
        <object type="text/html" data=https://www.google.com" 
    width="500px" height="500px"></object>
    </div>
<blink>